# SQL 2008 not performing parallelism with top clause

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Currently working on improving the efficiency of a few queries. After looking at the query plan I found that SQL is not performing parallelism when a top clause is in place, increasing the query time from 1-2s to several minutes.

The query in question is using a view with various joins and unions, I'm looking for a general answer/understanding as to why this is happening - google has thus far failed me.

Thanks

Comment: Is the `TOP` parameterised? If so maybe it just underestimates the number of rows because of parameter sniffing. If you are using `TOP (@variable)` it will always estimate 100 rows as it does not do variable sniffing at all. You can use `OPTION (RECOMPILE)`

Answer (score 2):

As you may be aware that

Generally, SQL Server processes queries in parallel in the following cases:

- When the number of CPUs is greater than the number of active connections.
- When the estimated cost for the serial execution of a query is higher than the query plan threshold (The estimated cost refers to the elapsed time in seconds required to execute the query serially.)

Certain types of statements cannot be processed in parallel unless they contain clauses, however. 
For example, UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE are not normally processed in parallel even if the related query meets the criteria.

But if the UPDATE or DELETE statements contain a WHERE clause, or an INSERT statement contains a SELECT clause, WHERE and SELECT can be executed in parallel. Changes are applied serially to the database in these cases.

To configure parallel processing, simply do the following:

1. **In the Server Properties dialog box, go to the Advanced page.**
2. **By default, the Max Degree Of Parallelism setting has a value of 0, which means that the maximum number of processors used for parallel processing is controlled automatically. Essentially, SQL Server uses the actual number of available processors, depending on the workload. To limit the number of processors used for parallel processing to a set amount (up to the maximum supported by SQL Server), change the Max Degree Of Parallelism setting to a value greater than 1. A value of 1 tells SQL Server not to use parallel processing.**
3. Large, complex queries usually can benefit from parallel execution. However, SQL Server performs parallel processing only when the estimated number of seconds required to run a serial plan for the same query is higher than the value set in the cost threshold for parallelism. **Set the cost estimate threshold using the Cost Threshold For Parallelism box on the Advanced page of the Server Properties dialog box. You can use any value from 0 through 32,767. On a single CPU, the cost threshold is ignored.**
4. Click OK. These changes are applied immediately. You do not need to restart the server.

You can use the stored procedure sp_configure to configure parallel processing. The Transact-SQL commands are:

```
exec sp_configure "max degree of parallelism", <integer value>
exec sp_configure "cost threshold for parallelism", <integer value>
```

Quoted from Technet article [Configure Parallel Processing in SQL Server 2008](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd320292.aspx)

Comment: So my problem is that the optimizer is making an inaccurate guess as to the cost of the query, believing that parallelism would hinder rather than help?

Comment: Well change the cost of the query as described above, if you think optimizer is unfair :)

Comment: As far as I can determine the above article discusses the threshold for parallelism, lowering which seems dangerous. As for changing the cost of the query itself, I'm not sure how? As it runs for several minutes I can only assume it more than surpasses the threshold?

Comment: 1. what is the number of CPU/Proc? 2. What is the mask affinity set to? What is max degree of parallelism set to?

Comment: 12 proc, the affinity mask is automatically set and the degree of parallelism is set to 0. (Also removing the top clause and inspecting the execution plan shows that parallelism takes place.)

Comment: can you tell me what you get if you change to rowcount instead of top in your query?

Comment: Rowcount yields the same result as top I'm afraid.

Comment: can you paste your query pls?

Comment: The view itself is particularly large, but as stated the query runs in 1-2 seconds. I'm mainly want to know why adding a top clause would cause sql to remove parallelism as a viable execution plan?

Comment: Ok, well TOP keyword actually delays the query if query contains ORDER BY clause, the reason being that the entire result set is selected into a worktable and sorted before the top N is ordered. This cannot be executed in parallel

Comment: The result set for this current query only consists of 336 rows. Furthermore excluding the ORDER BY clause gives no speed increase.

Comment: Sorry Iam unable to help...as I cannot work out based on information I have

Answer (score 1):

TOP automatically places the query into serial (non parallel mode). This is a restriction and cannot be overcome. Attempt using a rank where rand value=1 as a possible alternative to the TOP function...